# Why is it faster to access the DOM through a cached variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, domdocument

I am trying to improve my knowledge of javascript and while searching for some "best practices", someone pointed out to me that it is faster to cache the DOM document and then access it through that var instead of accessing the document object directly.

You can see the results here, on an edit I made on jsperf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-document-cached-vs-uncached/3 (edit: the title holds "jsquery" because that was the original test, my edit contains vanilla javascript, the framework makes no difference)

This really makes me curious. Basically I am introducing a new variable into the equation, how can that make things faster instead of slower?

As far as I know, "print a" should be better than "b = a; print b" (figure of speach)
What's different in this case?

Comment: You'd want to cache the result of an expensive query, not aliasing `document`...

Comment: Yet doing this is faster than accessing the document directly and it seems that there are many others doing this (YUI if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: For me there is a 2% difference - hardly worth talking about.

Comment: I've run it a few times and sometimes cached wins; sometimes uncached wins.

Comment: The difference is likely the result of variations in how much strain was on your processor when the tests ran - you effectively ran the same test twice in succession.

Comment: @BBog if you refer to `document` multiple times, you can alias it to  get a nice minification benefit. It has nothing to do with run-time performance.

Comment: 5-7% for me. While using some extensive js functions, in theory, it adds up nicely, but still, it's not about the efficiency, I'm just curious why it happens. I understand why it's good to cache a document element, a div for example, if you are going to reference it a lot since you are going directly to the part that interests you. But for the whole document? That's really odd magic, as Ned Batchelder said :))

Comment: @BBog The test is faulty because 99% of the work done in the test is not what it is supposed to be testing. Try http://jsperf.com/jquery-document-cached-vs-uncached/4

Comment: that's even faster than before :)) now the uncached access is 46% slower :/ that's an impressing increase in speed for the cached version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found an explanation [here](http://desalasworks.com/javascript-performance-techniques/) (the emphasis on the last part is mine):

> **Store pointer references to in-browser objects.** Use this technique to
>   reduce DOM traversal trips by storing references to browser objects
>   during instantiation for later usage. For example, if you are not
>   expecting your DOM to change you should store a reference to DOM or
>   jQuery objects you are going to use when your page is created; if you
>   are building a DOM structure such as a dialog window, make sure you
>   store a few handy reference to DOM objects inside it during
>   instantiation, so you dont need to find the same DOM object over an
>   over again when a user clicks on something or drags the dialog
>   window.If you haven’t stored a reference to a DOM object, and you need
>   to iterate inside a function, ***you can create a local variable
>   containing a reference to that DOM object, this will considerably
>   speed up the iteration as the local variable is stored in the most
>   accessible part of the stack***.

So, if I understand correctly, caching the DOM in a local variable makes it easier to access in the memory stack, therefore increasing the speed of execution.

Answer (score 2):

`document` is not like an ordinary Javascript variable.  There's no telling what odd magic is happening under the covers when accessing its attributes, especially the DOM, which may be created on demand from internal browser structures.

Comment: When you're accessing a variable aliasing `document` you are accessing `document`....